# validation for string input field in reactive forms

Tags: javascript, angular, validation

[This is my form and this shows errors only while clicking on submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyZGj.png)

I want this error to be shown while typing in the input field.

validation for string input field in reactive forms, when numbers are typed errors should be shown immediately like (enter only numbers), and when the numbers are removed the error should not be shown. pls, any ideas?

Comment: use ```document.querySelector('#myInput').addEventListener('input', function(){ });``` then add you validation code inside  the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time you can add your code.
You have to create an text to show when they are a error in a field, or add something like red border on input

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <label for="title" class="text-muted text-sm">Title</label>
  <span
    class="text-danger"
    *ngIf="form.get('title').errors &&
        form.get('title').hasError('required')">min 2 length</span>
  <input id="title" type="text" placeholder="" formControlName="title">
</div>
```

on typescript ( don't forget to import formGroup and formBuilder)

```
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
  title: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]]
  });
}
```

on css

```
.text-danger{
   color: red
 }
```

you can also directly add on input this code ( and create in css class valid and invalid)

```
[class.valid]="formGroup.get('title').valid && 
    (formGroup.get('title').dirty || formGroup.get('title').touched)"
[class.invalid]="formGroup.get('title').invalid && 
    (formGroup.get('title').dirty || formGroup.get('title').touched)"
```

Comment: thank you it worked, but I found other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number format you could use an input of `type="number"`.

As for validation, use the `updateOn: 'change'` option in your required every FormControl that needs to validate on change, like this:

```js
mobile: [
    null, {
        validators: [
            // your validators here
        ],
        asyncValidators: [
            // your async validators here
        ],
        updateOn: 'change'
    }
]
```

This way the validators will be called everytime the value of the control changes, i.e. with every keypress.

Comment: thanks, it was useful, but I found some other alternatives.

<span style=" color: red"
          *ngIf="(basicformcontrol.phone.touched || submitted) &&
            (basicformcontrol.phone.errors?.required || basicformcontrol. phone.invalid)">*Enter a valid number
        </span>
        <span
          style="color: red"
          *ngIf="basicform.get('phone').hasError('min length)"
          >*enter 10 digits</span
        >

used this code to show multiple errors, and I restricted string in phone number input so I can only type numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Try this amazing library called [React-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/)

In this library, There are [4 stages of getting data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uOaS.png) from the form inputs.

Recently, I've used it and it's very amazing and straight forward to use... Please visit the official website and watch those 2 videos.

Comment: Your library does not work in this case, since it's meant for React, but Angular is used in the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).